# Error de Parametro Requerido desde un Reporte BIRT llamado desde Otro

Tags: eclipse, report

El Error que presenta es este:

```
+ org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Required parameter client is not set.
```

El reporte cuando lo estaba probando en local llamaba correctamente a su hijo, pero ahora que se ha subido al cliente web uno de los reportes llamados desde otro genera este error.

Podemos ver que el parametro client en este caso no es establecido... 
Estoy trabajando en BIRT y no le veo mucha diferencia entre un reporte que funciona y el otro que no.. en los parametros del reporte estan muy similares entre el que no funciona y el que si.

A caso esto tiene que ver con los parametros en el `DataSet`?
¿Les ha pasado similar?

Answer (score 0):

Me sucedio tras usar las librerias del Runtime de BIRT, lo que hice fue mejor evitar el runtime para el web page y generar uno a mi manera con las librerias directas del folder de plugins de eclipse BIRT.

De esa manera mando llamar el reporte desde una clase y un parametro dado desde una caja de texto.